# CocoaPods Installation for pods

Tags: ruby, installation, cocoapods, version

I am trying to install the CocoaPods but I am receiving the below error:

> ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
> The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.6. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6` and then running the current command again
> activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

my current ruby version is:

> ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]

I haven't done this cocoapods installation before, I need to install some pods to my project but before that i am not able to install these.. Someone would help me to get this right.
How to resolve this error and how to proceed after this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6` and then running the current command again ?

Comment: Yeah this worked, after installing "gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6" able to install cocoapods, thanks @koen

Comment: I just repeated what is inside the error message you shared.